# Type checking in redux forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

Let's suppose we have following types defined:

```
interface ThisIsMyForm  {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}

type FormFieldsType = keyof ThisIsMyForm;

const field1: FormFieldsType = "c";

const field2 = "c" as FormFieldsType;
```

and I want to have type checking for form name using TypeScript:

```
<Field name={ "FirstName" as FormFieldsType }>

<Field name={field2}>
```

In first case code gets compiled even when I use values which doesn't belong to `FormFieldsType`. In second case it works but it requires to declare extra variables. Field name is of type: string. Can I somehow cast with type check?

Comment: I come with  something like this:
`

function field2<T, M extends T[keyof T], W extends M[keyof M]>(input: T, prop: keyof T, prop2: keyof M): string {
    return prop + "." + prop2;
} 

const zzz: ThisIsMyForm = {
    Address: null,
    FirstName: null,
    LastName: null
};
field2(zzz, "Address", "City")
`

but it don't solve the probably the way I like

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you want. What type should be of the property `name` of the `<Field>` component?

Answer (score 0):

I've end up with something like this:

```
function formFieldsAccessor<TForm>() {
return function nested<
    K extends keyof TForm, 
    L extends keyof TForm[K] = keyof TForm[K], 
    M extends keyof TForm[K][L] = keyof TForm[K][L]
    >(prop1: K, prop2?: L, prop3?: M): string {
    return prop1
        + (prop2 ? "." + prop2 : "")
        + (prop3 ? "." + prop3 : "");
}
}
```

so now I can do:

```
export const loginDtoFields = formFieldsAccessor<LoginDto>();
```

and inside form:

```
<Field
       name={loginDtoFields('email')}
       type="text"
       placeholder="Please enter your e-mail address"
       component={renderInput}
  />
```

as result I have type checking in form fields.

When we join this with TypingsGenerator which generates types from server side classes, my code stops to compile when server side dto is changed, so I can quickly detect invalid field.